# Не обрабатывается ошибка 404 Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, http-status-code-404

Следовал всем возможным инструкциям в интернете, но почему-то всегда отображется только стандартная страница ошибки вебсервера. В конфиге прописал нужный контроллер и действие, в контроллере создал действие и в нем вывожу мою страницу ошибки, но все равно показывает стандартную страницу, почему так?

Comment: Добрый вечер. Какую стандартную страницу? Страницу error.php самого framework? Или какую? Каким инструкциям следовали? Дайте ссылки. Приведите пример своего кода. Покажите как в контроллере, конфигурационном файле Вы настраивали.

Comment: Отображает стандартную ошибку Apache "Object not found. The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please..." и т.д. Настроено сейчас как указано по этой ссылке https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/runtime-handling-errors/#using-error-actions . В errorHandel указал  `'errorAction' => 'site/error',`, в контроллере site создал действие actionError в нем `if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) $this->render('error', $error);`

Comment: Я не пойму, Вы хотите подключить свою страницу ошибки?

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос кодом.

Comment: Вы не настроили Апач для работы с Yii2

Comment: Может путь не так прописали?